# Does making a ground based telescope larger always give you a better resolution?? why?? or why not?

Tags: telescope, newtonian-telescope, telescope-lens

i just don't really understand this topic.

Comment: Welcome to Astronomy. You haven't told us what you already know about the resolution of telescopes. Why, for example, you think that a larger telescope would give a better resolution? Why do you mention "ground based"? Do you think being in space makes a difference? Have you searched for this topic in books or on the web? Which web pages did you read and what did you learn. Why have you tagged "newtonian telescope"? Please edit to improve your question.

Comment: I'm going to make a guess and assume this is a homework question as well (forgive me if I'm wrong). Such questions are not necessarily forbidden here, but the goal should be, as James K pointed out, that you show us the logic of what your thought process is and what exactly you don't understand. Our goal is to help you understand the concepts, not provide the correct answer for your homework questions.

Answer (score 2):

The diffraction limit of telescope optics, for apertures large compared to the wavelength of light, is inversely proportional to the diameter of the aperture. See the relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system).

For moderate to large telescopes with simple optics this resolution limit is usually not realisable due to seeing. The seeing limit is due to thermal inhomogeneity and turbulence in the atmosphere between the telescope and the target. See this [Sky at Night page](http://www.skyatnightmagazine.com/feature/general-guide/guide-seeing-and-atmospheric-transparency).

To some extent the seeing limit can be overcome using adaptive optics. See the relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_optics).